# ok to ask why user got deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-users

I'm not sure if there's any policy about revealing why a particular user got deleted:

user4739890 (known to those who loved him as **@aggggg**)

I was particularly fond of **@aggggg** because I just answered a 300 pnt bounty of his. So, as you can imagine, his passing hit me very hard.

The bounty was high for the question, though the amount of work that went in wasn't a small amount (yeah, I'm annoyed).

So I would like to know, as long as it doesn't break some rule about privacy.

I knew him less than 24 hours, but he will be missed for a long time to come :(

Comment: More than likely, he was deleted because he asked to be. In that very likely case, thats all that SE even knows.

Comment: Asked to be deleted or deleted for reasons of moderation either way you're not likely to get much info.

Comment: @apaul34208, Yeah it had to be one of those. I suspect he was deleted. He seemed very happy with SO? I'll certainly miss his bounty.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I can't know for sure, but it doesn't seem likely that he asked to be deleted. Was very happy getting help. But the question was a little weak for 300pnt bounty. I have a feeling he was whacked.

Comment: I think aggggg was a sockpuppet of another user. If you recall (and I won't call out who it was) it was that other user that offered the bounty, not aggggg thereby taking themself from 304 to 4 rep which seemed rather unusual.

Comment: @RobertLongson, that kind of makes sense. But if you're talking about the bounty from yesterday I thought agggg offered the bounty. Can I have points from "he who will not be named"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The account was deleted because it was being used to evade system limitations. It was by far not the only account that got this treatment.

I'm sorry you were caught up in this, but the bounty should never have been offered in the first place.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm kind of sore cause it was work through his mess or the gym, and I chose wrong. But I get it and appreciate the explanation

Comment: I'm really happy that there was an explanation too: this is great.   I was fully expecting no answer (which would have been understandable, but not as good!)